How to run v4l2 capture media example and how to get stream from webcam in realtime?
I'm building an RTSP server that can get streams from webcams. I'm planning to use v4l2 and I found an example of v4l2 capturing webcams but when I run it it seems no data is written to the output file. Please help me .
This is code v4l2 media capture example:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.9/media/uapi/v4l/capture.c.html
I want to get the output of v4l2 as an unsigned char array containing h264 frames because my server is receiving input file.media.h264.h and audio.g711a.h as unsigned char.
